# IE11 in edge mode not displaying disabled dropdown text

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2t713gkr/

```
/*css style for IE*/
select[disabled='disabled']::-ms-value {
  color: #daa520;
}
```

When using IE11 (in edge mode), any disabled dropdowns appear empty...  while the same code in Firefox and Chrome showed the selected value, just unable to be changed...

I've looked for various solutions, and tried a few (as implemented in the fiddle) but nothing seems to work...

Any idea how to get disabled text to appear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select:disabled::-ms-value` instead of `select[disabled='disabled']`.  Your JSFiddle has `<select name="drpProjType" id="drpProjType" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;" onchange="" tabindex="11" disabled="">`, so the css selector is looking for an element with an attribute named "disabled" that has a value of "disabled".